# Rake assets are generated twice when precompiling them once from command line and once from within a Ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, assets, precompile

When I do `$ rake assets:precompile` from the command line twice, then the assets are only generated once (as expected).

When I execute `system 'rake assets:precompile'` twice within a Ruby file, then the assets are also only generated once (as expected).

But when I execute it once from the command line and once from the Ruby file, then the assets are generated twice!

```
application-3e5c3563c16dfbc76bb833355133818d.js
application-3e5c3563c16dfbc76bb833355133818d.js.gz
application-61c5fbc18ff978365b43849b5787130e.css
application-61c5fbc18ff978365b43849b5787130e.css.gz
application-bb95b4b82324f57eb5d4ef0d20d5a68d.js
application-bb95b4b82324f57eb5d4ef0d20d5a68d.js.gz
application-c17c2cec3bacccb8ef58471e949679f2.css
application-c17c2cec3bacccb8ef58471e949679f2.css.gz
manifest-1627575ea003fb94ae02acecd73aecef.json
```

Why's that? And how can it be prevented? Thank you.

**The reason why I'm doing this:**

I'm searching for unused CSS selectors throughout my application. I [forked](https://github.com/aanand/deadweight/pull/22) the old [DeadWeight](https://github.com/aanand/deadweight) gem and updated it so it's working with newer versions of Rails.

The problem is that I need the fully compiled `application.css` file when initializing DeadWeight, so I [precompile](https://github.com/aanand/deadweight/pull/22/files#diff-2ffd710037cdc8fb7435ac3dc905c2a8R15) it from within DeadWeight. And there I noticed that when there's already a precompiled version that was precompiled from the console (and not from within DeadWeight), it's not overwritten! So I have to manually remove it first (by doing another `rake assets:clobber/clean`) which isn't nice.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: I added some more explanation.

Comment: Ah, so you ask why assets work as they do? I think Rails Guides will be a good read for you. Or you can simply clean the assets dir every time. But rest assured - this is expected behaviour.

Comment: I'm simply curious how Rake notices a difference between calling it from the console and calling it from within a Ruby file...?

Comment: Ok, I did some more digging and this is strange indeed. Maybe files are changes for some reason between first and second compilation?